# Spring Kafka Consumer with At Least One Semantics

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

This is my requirement

1. I need to read data from 2 topics .
2. I need to read 1 message at a time and call DB  .
3. Once DB call is completed (irrespective of succes or failure ) i need to commit the kafka offset .

I have done the below configuration .So is this the correct way to implemt AT LEAST ONCE semantic  while reading and processing 1 message at a time.

I am fine with duplicate messages being read by Kafka Consumer.(although will like to reduce duplicates).

```
 @EnableKafka
    public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory() {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "grpid-mytopic");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
    
        
    
            return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
        }
    
        @Bean
        KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
            factory.setConcurrency(2);
    
            return factory;
        }



 


@KafkaListener(topics = "mytopic-1")
        public void consumeFromTopic1(String message, ConsumerRecordMetadata meta)
        {
            
             dbservice.callDB(message);
    
        }
        
        @KafkaListener(topics = "mytopic-2")
        public void consumeFromTopic2(String message, ConsumerRecordMetadata meta)
        {
            
             dbservice.saveInDB(message);
    
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG` should be false, the listener container will reliably commit the offset, in a deterministic fashion, when the listener exits.

Comment: If I enable ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG false then  do i need to commit the offset manually ?

Comment: ok i just some POC work and understood what you mean.Will AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG should be `earliest` or `latest` .And what if processing takes  more time than `AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG`

Comment: No, you don't have to commit manually, the listener container will commit for you. `enable.auto.commit` is less reliable because it commits only based on an interval. The default `AckMode` is `BATCH` - it is identical to `RECORD` when `max.poll.records` is `. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#committing-offsets

Comment: Thnaks Understood